# Custom Object as a @RequestParam

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a paginated endpoint that looks like this /api/clients?range=0-25.

I'd like the getClients() method in my ClientController to directly receive an instance of a custom Range object rather than having to validate a "0-25" String but I'm having trouble figuring this out.

```
@Getter
final class Range {

    @Min(0)
    private Integer offset = 0;

    @Min(1)
    private Integer limit = 25;
}
```

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(params = { "range" })
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllClients(@RequestParam(value = "range", required = false) QueryRange queryRange, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure how to instruct the Controller to correctly deserialize the "0-25" string into the Range...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`Converter<S, T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html), as shown below:

```
@Component
public class RangeConverter implements Converter<String, Range> {

    @Override
    public Range convert(String source) {
        String[] values = source.split("-");
        return new Range(Integer.valueOf(values[0]), Integer.valueOf(values[1]));
    }
}
```

You also could handle invalid values according to your needs. If you use the above converter as is, the attempt to convert an invalid value such as `1-x` will result in a [`ConversionFailedException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/ConversionFailedException.html).

Comment: The problem with this approach (and the other one I think) is that I can't adequately react to formatting issues. Say I send 'range=0-bob'. With the Converter<S, T> approach my custom exception isn't caught in my ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and so the client just gets a 400 with no detail. With the PropertyEditorSupport approach this works and so I can send a body with a specific error message but I can't tell the context in which the Range is used. That's fine if a Range object is only used for query parameters called 'range' but if that were not the case there would be no way of telling

Comment: @ChambreNoire You could, for example, catch whichever exception is thrown when attempting to parse the value, rethrow a custom exception (such as `InvalidRangeException`) and [handle it accordingly](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).

Comment: You mean directly in the Controller ? Sure that would be a way of doing it yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following it seems :

```
public class QueryRangeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^([1-9]\\d*|0)-([1-9]\\d*|0)$");

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        final QueryRange range = new QueryRange();

        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(text);

        if (matcher.find()) {

            range.setOffset(Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1)));
            range.setLimit(Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2)));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("OI"); // todo - replace
        }
        setValue(range);
    }
}
```

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(QueryRange.class, new QueryRangeEditor());
}
```

But @cassiomolin's looks cleaner...